# Create .Properties file using powershell with data in it

Tags: powershell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
How to create a new .properties file using powershell with below data name it as vars.properties
```

```
username=abcd
buildnumber=1234
isSuccess=true
```

Is there any way to create with this data in vars.properties file. Later I want use this file in Groovy to extract the data easily.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure about your query.

But if you want to use PowerShell to create a vars.properties file and push those values in the file.

You can just execute the following commands in PowerShell

```
New-Item vars.properties -ItemType File
Add-Content vars.properties "username=abcd"
Add-Content vars.properties "buildnumber=1234"
Add-Content vars.properties "isSuccess=true"
```

Comment: Thank you @Deˣ . this is I am looking. I did like this and its working as well "username=abcd" | Out-File "C:\\test\\one.properties" -Encoding ASCII  
Add-Content "C:\\test\\one.properties" "buildnumber=1234"
Add-Content "C:\\test\\one.properties" "isSuccess=true"